# How to understand this sentence if it contains "nor" without "either"?

Tags: conjunctions, negation, contractions

> Unprotected passwords weren’t compromised **nor** were payment cards as
>   the latter weren’t stored on the affected system.

Comment: The negative _nor_ complements the previous negative in _weren't,_ which is a contraction for _were **not.**_ (We don't use _nor_ with _either._ We use _nor_ with _neither,_ and _or_ with _either._)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negative word 'nor' means not eiher; also not.  You can use "neither ....nor" in a sentence, not "either....nor".  You can also use the negative word "not" in the first clause and nor in the second clause by inverting the subject and verb.  For examples:

I'm not going, nor is John.

She doesn't like them, nor does Jeff.

Likewise, the sentence presented below by the OP is correct grammatically:

Unprotected passwords weren't compromised, nor were payments cards.

Alternatively, you can use not either instead of nor in these sentences as follows:

I'm not going and John isn't either.

She diesn't like them and Jeff doesn't either.

Unprotected passwords weren't compromised and payment cards weren't either.

Comment: So the full scentence can be written like this: Neither unprocected passwords nor payment cards were compromised, and payment cards weren't stored on the affected system.

Comment: Yes, but as I point out in my answer, even if you understand the grammar, it's an unnecessarily confusing sentence.  There are better ways to write this that would be clear and to the point.

Comment: Agree with you, Andrew. It make readers confused, especially for those non-native English speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what the author probably wants to say, but it's clumsy English.  The "neither ... nor" construct is supposed to be used to tie two things together that share some kind of common trait or result, but here you have two separate things happening:  Unprotected passwords were not compromised **and** payment cards were not stored on the affected system (so they also were not compromised).

The author provides information on the payment cards but not the unprotected passwords, so as written the sentence raises questions.  I get that both things were not compromised, but without some kind of explanation they don't really go together and the "nor" is not good English style.

Comment: In this sentence there is nothing clumsy nor noteworthy. _Passwords were **not** compromised, **nor** were payment cards._ This is just plain old English! The "as" clause isn't germane to the usage at all. (_Because_ would be a better choice, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: It's not grammatically incorrect, but the reason why NeilWang is having trouble understanding it is because it's poor English style.  These are two different things, and it's useful for those learning English to understand that sometimes sentences are confusing simply because they're poorly written, and not because they employ some kind of unusual but useful grammatical structure.

Comment: The reason he had a problem is that he did not recognize that the _not_ in _weren't_  corresponds to the negative _nor._ He tells us exactly this in the title of his question.

Comment: Again (and I don't want to beat a dead horse) there's good grammar and then there's good style.  A better, more complete sentence would have been easy to understand no matter which grammar structure was used.  *I* don't even know what the author is trying to say. because anyone who understands data security can't help but wonder how the 'unprotected' passwords didn't get compromised.  More importantly, though, this is poor English style that shouldn't be emulated even if it doesn't technically break any rules.

Comment: The question does not address style, which in any case is purely a matter of individual taste and judgment.